# JavaScript not creating header inside div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
function search() {
  var searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar");
  if (searchbar.value != null) {
    var searchResult = document.createElement("h2");
    searchResult.value = "Search results for " + searchbar.value;
    document.getElementById("question-render").appendChild(searchResult);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CodeGitOverflow</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/navbar.css' />
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/search.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Div for navbar -->
  <div class="navbar">
    <!-- Div for header -->
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Welcome to CodeGitOverflow</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Div for search -->
    <div class="searchbar">
      <form action="javascript:search()">
        <input id="searchbar" type="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Search for question">
        <p>Search for a question</p>
        <noscript>This website won't work without JavaScript enabled.</noscript>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Div for links -->
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a onclick="javascript:this.style.display = 'none';" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="askQuestion.html">Ask a question</a></li>
        <li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question-render" id="question-render">

    <div class="questions-header">
      <h1>Questions Asked</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="questions-render-section" id="questions-render-section">
      <p>No questions asked yet.</p>
      <p>Have a question? <a href="askQuestion.html">Ask a question</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Inside the HTML code,

There is a div with the ID of 'questions-render' which is used to render the search result as an  tag

Inside the JavaScript code,

- I get the search bar by its identifier.
- I checked if the value of the search bar's value is not equal to null. If it isn't I created an 'h2' with the variable name `searchResult`,
- I set the value of the search result variable to 'Search Results for' + search Bar's value
- Then I append that to the `question-render` div

Comment: `h2` elements don't have a value. Use `searchResult.innerText` instead of `searchResult.value`

Answer (score 1):

You should add `innerText` to the header tag instead of setting up its value:

```
searchResult.innerText = "Search results for " + searchbar.innerText;
```